# React context api catalog lazy load

Tags: reactjs, react-context

In my react web app I need to load the whole catalog (`metrics`) and cache it on client side in order to let all components in my application use it. To store this catalog on client side I want to use react context api and I prefer to load this catalog lazily to avoid long app start.

Here's my solution:

I declare metrics context, exporting only one function `getMetrics` which returns promise from metrics array. This promise is created only once and is stored as `Ref` in context provider for future `getMetrics` executions.

**metricsContext.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { createContext, useCallback, useRef } from 'react'
import { MetricModel, metricsApi } from '../api/metricsApi'

interface MetricsContext {
    getMetrics: () => Promise<MetricModel[]>
}

export const metricsContext = createContext<MetricsContext>({ getMetrics: () => Promise.resolve([]) })

interface Props {
    children: React.ReactNode
}
export const MetricsContextProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
    const metricsPromise = useRef<Promise<MetricModel[]>>()

    const getMetrics = useCallback(async () => {
        if (metricsPromise.current == null) {
            metricsPromise.current = metricsApi.getAll()
        }

        return await metricsPromise.current
    }, [])

    const { Provider } = metricsContext
    return <Provider value={{ getMetrics: getMetrics }}>{children}</Provider>
}
```

To use this context in the component I need to import context into it and resolve promise by executing `useEffect`.

**SomeComponent.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { MetricModel } from '../../../api/metricsApi'
import { metricsContext } from '../../../state/metricsContext'

export const SomeComponent = () => {
    const cntxt = useContext(metricsContext)

    const [metrics, setMetrics] = useState<MetricModel[]>([])
    useEffect(() => {
        cntxt.getMetrics().then(res => setMetrics(res))
    }, [cntxt])

    return metrics.map(m => <div key={m.id}>{m.name}</div>)
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it normal to store `Promise` in ref?
2. Is it normal that context provider makes http requests lazily?